# What is the best way to verify authentication token of different type of users?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Let's say I have 10 routes and each route is accessible to only a specific type of user. When a user logins, a token is generated.These user tokens are generated with their `_id` and a token secret which is stored in `.env` file.

Normally token verification for each user type is done with separate functions because different type of user has different token secret. For example, user1's token secret maybe `TOKEN_SECRET_USER2 = 6ygfewf6hj`, and user2's token maybe `TOKEN_SECRET_USER1 = 87uhjkaf89`.

And when any request is made to a route, the user token is verified to see if the user can access that route or not.

Here's two example route accessible to different user types,

```
// Route accessible to user type 1
router.get("/foo", verifyTokenUSER1, async (req, res) => {
    // All the good stuff
});

// Route accessible to user type 2
router.post("/bar", verifyTokenUSER2, async (req, res) => {
    // All the good stuff
});
```

Here's some method of verification module looks like,

```
// Verification for user 1
const verifyTokenUSER1 = (req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send();

    try {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_USER1);

        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send();
    }
};

// Verification for user 2
const verifyTokenUSER2 = (req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send();

    try {
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_USER2);

        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send();
    }
};
```

As you can see, there's only one change in the above methods, which is the access token secret of the user types.

I would like to verify them using 1(one) single function if possible. But I can't pass any value as parameter to the verify methods. So, how can I remove duplication here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually *can* pass a parameter to the verify method if you use `bind` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)):

```js
// Route accessible to user type 1
router.get("/foo", verifyToken.bind(null, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_USER1), async (req, res) => {
    // All the good stuff
});

// Route accessible to user type 2
router.post("/bar", verifyToken.bind(null, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_USER2), async (req, res) => {
    // All the good stuff
});
```

the `bind` method of a function here is receiving 2 parameters: first, the `this` context for the function, and second, the first argument. It returns a new function that will receive the provided token as the first argument, and will receive `req, res, next` as the next arguments.

```js
const verifyToken = (tokenSecret, req, res, next) => {

    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send();

    try {
        jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret);

        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send();
    }
};
```

Another way to do this that is equivalent is building a verification method "factory" which returns a verification function that has a closure ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) on the token:

```js
// Route accessible to user type 1
router.get("/foo", getTokenVerifier(process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_USER1), async (req, res) => {
    // All the good stuff
});

// Route accessible to user type 2
router.post("/bar", getTokenVerifier(process.env.TOKEN_SECRET_USER2), async (req, res) => {
    // All the good stuff
});

// this function returns a new function, with a closure on the provided tokenSecret
const getTokenVerifier = (tokenSecret) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.header("auth-token");
    if (!token) return res.status(401).send();

    try {
        jwt.verify(token, tokenSecret);

        next();
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(401).send();
    }
  }

}
```